# count how many times I remove an element in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I need to keep track of how many times I remove an element from my list. I have something like list remove(an element).

I tried:

```
c=0
list remove(an element)
c+=1
```

Comment: list.remove(an element)*

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Good approach. Should work correctly.

Comment: when I print c, is giving me 1,1,1,1,1,1... and not 6 for example

Comment: Can you post your complete code and how you ran it.

Comment: @hanna Your counter probably is inside a for-loop as well as your print(counter) that's why you cant get the total count

Comment: Is the above code inside for loop then you either need to use global variable or clouser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must introduce a for loop throughout the list and then use the counter `c`. and u must initialize `c` outside the loop and print `c` outside the loop, like:

```
c=0
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if element in list:
        list.remove(element)
        c+=1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the list length before the removal and after will tell you how many you removed.

```
pre_len = len(list)
list = [x for x in list if x != needle]
num_removed = pre_len - len(list)
```